# Retrieving unique results from a relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am developing a page where I want to display unique results from a relation and the entire result.
The entrie result I retreive it as follows:

```
$media = Media::whereHas('block', function ($query) {
            $query->where('identifier', "page");
        })->with(["texts" => function ($query) use ($language) {
            $query->where("language_id", $language->id);
        }])->get();
```

In the texts relation is a title field where I want to get only the unique results from.

I tried to do another query for it but it didn't work

```
$media = Media::whereHas('block', function ($query) use ($blockId) {
            $query->where('identifier', "page");
        })->with(["texts" => function ($query) use ($language) {
            $query->where("language_id", $language->id);
        }])->distinct("texts.title")->get();
```

How can I achieve that? and can I do it from the same result ( not another query )

edit: 
what I want is a list of unique titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relationship queries are performed separately from the main query, any logic in retrieving relationships must go in the `with` function:

```
$media = Media::whereHas('block', function ($query) use ($blockId) {
            $query->where('identifier', $blockId);
        })->with(["mediaTexts" => function ($query) use ($language) {
            $query->where("language_id", $language->id)
                  ->select('title')
                  ->distinct();
        }])->get();
```

Here each `Media` object retrieved should have distinct titles in the `mediaTexts` relationship. If you want the entire relationship data things will get more complicated.

To get distinct titles of media texts among all `Media` objects after you've retrieved them you can do:

```
$media = Media::whereHas('block', function ($query) use ($blockId) {
            $query->where('identifier', $blockId);
        })->with("mediaTexts")->get();
$titles = $media->pluck('mediaTexts.title')->unique();
```

Comment: well, I already got the entire relationship. Sorry, I may not explained my need well. I want unique titles among all media as a list, not on each one of them. 
the result of the query shows an empty object

Comment: You mean something like `$media->pluck('metiaTexts.title')->unique()` ?

Comment: yes, something like this but it didn't work like that. I have to write 
$media->pluck('texts.0.title')->unique()
how to return the relation data as an object not an array?